# listing secrets for Azure function in Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-functions, kudu

I've been following along with some of the examples [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/issues/1748) using the [functions API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Functions-API) trying to get the secrets for functions deployed.

I'm logged in as the subscription owner via `Login-AzureRmAccount` and pulling the access token out of the token cache.  Using that, I use `Invoke-RestMethod` to call into the ARM API to try to list secrets per the functions API.  Example:

```
# $accessToken is from TokenCache
$uri = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/[my-subscription-guid]/resourceGroups/SampleResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/SampleFunctionApp/functions/SampleFunction/listsecrets?api-version=2015-08-01"
Invoke-RestMethod `
    -Method Post `
    -Headers @{
        "Authorization" = "Bearer $accessToken"
    } `
    -Uri $uri
```

Azure returns a 403, claiming the webapp is stopped.  The function app is running, the permissions *should* check out as I'm the owner.  I've tried bouncing the service to no avail.  (It's worth mentioning that the above approach works with other resources fine.)

What am I missing?  Is there a setting in the function app I need to tweak?  Alternatively, is there another way to get the secrets, either from the `AzureRm` family of cmdlets or another API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, in order to prevent CSRF attacks, the Kudu API requires an explicit `User-Agent` and `Content-Type` (source [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/1806)).